# PC boot takes to long

Tags: boot, desktop-computer

I am facing problem with pc boot. There is very long time between power on pc and show post message on screen. Sometimes it take minutes (5-10) to show Asus logo. After showing logo Windows 10 boot normally.

After I startup PC and for example reboot it, i don`t have a same problem. I look on BIOS settings and there is fast boot enabled, and ssd is first option for boot.

I check power cables, and replace them. Also I opened PC and remove external graphic card and try to boot with internal card on mother board and still same problem.

Is there any suggestion what to check/do next?

Regards

Comment: Update your BIOS and all drivers. Reset your BIOS settings to defaults.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I try with reset BIOS to default and no look for now. Sometimes PC boots in less than 2 minutes, but sometime it doesn`t boot at all. I will proceed with bios update and will check all drivers.

Comment: Hello, It sure is strange. Are you hearing a beep soon after pressing the power button? Can the power button (push button) be faulty? Crazy guess I know but since even the logo takes time I would start suspecting hardware issues.

Comment: Hi, very strange behaviour. When I press power button, every light blinks (power button have blue light, green light from dvd) like before problem. Same with sounds, I hear every sound like before problem. I doubted on graphic card, and I removed it and try boot with integrated from motherboard and same